# Q-Learning, chosen action takes place with a probability

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, stochastic-process, mdp

In my problem I have predefined state and action spaces but when the agent decides to take an action,

- this action can take place as desired
- action can take place partially
- action not applicable at all

So the outcome of the action at each step depends on some other parameter that the agent does not know. Is there a way to model this problem with Q-learning?

Thanks,

I preferred Q-learning instead of MDP because I do not have pre-defined transition matrix.